# Bind first value and remove all other repeating value from a ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a scenario to bind a html table using angular js. In my table i need to show an a tag based on another column value(Payment Status). If its fully paid no need to show the a tag, else need to show it for very next element. I am a new one in angular.

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Month</th>
         <th>Installement</th>
         <th>PaymentAmount</th>
         <th>PaymentDate</th>
         <th>Payment Status</th>
         <th>Pay</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr dir-paginate="row in rowCollection|orderBy:type:reverse|filter:searchKeyword|itemsPerPage:maxsize">
         <td>{{row.Month}}</td>
         <td>{{row.MonthlyInstallement}}</td>
         <td>{{row.PaymentAmount}}</td>
         <td>{{row.PaymentDate}}</td>
         <td>{{row.PaymentStatus}}</td>
         <td ng-if="row.PaymentStatus == 'UNPAID'">
            <a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">Pay Online</a>
         </td>
         <td ng-if="row.PaymentStatus == 'FULLY_PAID'">
            <a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;"></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function bindFinanceDetails() {
    var finUrl = baseurl + 'api/FinancialStatement/GetCarFinanceInfo';
    var req = {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            LoginID: LoginID,
            ContractNumber: 11170200669,
            CustomerId: 2355898046
        },
        url: finUrl,
        headers: {
            RequestedPlatform: "Web",
            RequestedLanguage: cookiePreferredLanguage,
            Logintoken: $cookieStore.get('LoginToken'),
            LoginId: LoginID
        }
    };
    $http(req).then(function(response) {
        var getData = response.data.FinanceList;
        $scope.rowCollection = getData;

    }, function(error) {
        toastr.error($filter('translate')('Error Occured'));
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: do unique:'payementStatus' or 'pay'

Comment: Maybe angular-filter can solve that https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Answer (score 0):

A quite hacky solution will be something like the following (just showing you the needed change in the unpaid td element):

```
<td ng-if="row.PaymentStatus === 'UNPAID'" ng-show="$index === data.payOnlineIndex" 
    ng-init="data.payOnlineIndex = (!data.payOnlineIndex || (data.payOnlineIndex > $index)) ? $index : data.payOnlineIndex">
   <a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">Pay Online</a>
</td>
```

This way ng-init will run for all unpaid elements, setting the smallest index to the payOnlineIndex variable. ng-show will make sure to only show that one element that has the smallest index.

I encapsulate payOnlineIndex with a data object to keep a stable reference to it. This also requires the following addition to the controller code:

```
$scope.data = { payOnlineIndex: null };
```

See a working jsFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t3vktv0r/

Another option is running your filter and orderBy in the controller, searching for the first occurrence of an "unpaid" row, and marking that element for the "pay online" feature with some flag you can test with ng-if in your view.

Comment: I didnt understand, Can you explain little bit more, what you mean be '$index === payOnlineIndex'

Comment: Sure: in the ng-init I set value to a parameter called payOnlineIndex (only in case it wasn't already set or it had a higher index than set, because we want it to have the smallest value). The value I set is the $index supplied by the ng-repeat we're inside.
Then we only show the <a> element using ng-show if the element's $index value equals to the payOnlineIndex that was set.

This causes each element to set payOnlineIndex, and the one with the smallest $index will "win the race" and get his $index saved, thus showing its <a> element.

Comment: What is "payOnlineIndex" here.? Its not working for me. I am getting the below error. "Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assing a value to a non l-value http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/lval..... at at pre (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js:24272:15) <td ng-if="row.PaymentStatus === 'UNPAID'" ng-show="$index === payOnlineIndex" ng-init="(!payOnlineIndex || payOnlineIndex >"

Comment: @Jzl Ok, I've edited the ng-init which seems to cause this error. Give it another try, if that won't work we'll move its logic to a controller function :)

Comment: Now there is no Error, But I am getting the same result which i have mentioned in above image

Comment: @Jzl you are right, sorry about that. Updated the answer yet again and took no chances - tested it in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3vktv0r/
Notice you need to add a small part to the controller as well.
Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I handled this from back end controller. Its working fine now